# Classify book titles into categories

Tags: text-classification

I have 10,000 book names sorted into 50 categories. This is my training data.
I want to sort 2,000 or more names to sort with more incoming. What is the simplest way I could do this?
So my training data is just this:
Book Name              Category
Meditations            Philosophy
....
I could put this in a JSON format easily.
I searched around and found pretty large data sets for text classification with thousands of books. But what I need is something that uses a simple data format and not more than a few lines of code, maybe in Python:

```
import classifier from some_pkg
c = classifier()
c.read_json_training_data("ExistingCategorizedBooks.json")
c.train()
c.read_json_new_data("NewBookNames.json")
c.classify()
c.print_categories()
```

Perhaps something like the above with a few packages to install in my Python env.
The book titles are usually long and are quite descriptive. Most are about science, economics, travel etc so they do describe the book reasonably well e.g. Contours of the World Economy. I am not looking for extremely high accuracy.

Comment: Are you sure the titles contain enough information to make accurate classifications? After all, *The Catcher in the Rye* isn’t a sports story, and *Seabiscuit* isn’t about a pastry chef on the Titanic.

Comment: Yes, most are technical, economic, commerce related so they are usually quite descriptive.